# GCM in unity using EtceteraAndroid plugin and Urban Airship

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to use push notifications on Android game made in unity 3.5. These are the steps I made:

I purchased asset called EtceteraAndroid by prime31 and create urbanairship app on its portal. Then I modify airshipconfig file like this:

gcmSender = My_Proj_number here
transport = gcm
developmentAppKey = devkey
developmentAppSecret = dev secret key
productionAppKey = devkey
productionAppSecret = dev secret key (as I have no publishing account of Urban Airship)
inProduction = false

- I create google Account and got GCM enabled there, copy server API key to UrbanAirship GCM API key
- I've added some permissions mentioned here [Using GCM, Urban Airship to send Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787354/using-gcm-urban-airship-to-send-push-notification)
- Inside code, I call enable Urbanair push function which is available in EtceteraAndroid plugin.
- I build and run apk on my android device.
- I dont find any APPID registered on UrbanAirship portal and so get no notifications on my android device :(

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved it? I asked Prime31 and they said Urban Airship support has been dropped in the Android version of Etcetera-plugin. Have you found any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to sort out issues relating to the Urban Airship plugin as well.

According to Prime 31, it would seem like things should just work out of the box. but as you might have already noticed, GCM support has been deprecated and Prime's plugin still relies on C2DM.

[Perhaps you should also post on the following forum thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/92154-Prime31-Android-Plugins-Officially-Live!/page71) as this is where discussions have been happening on this topic..


Having said that, I can get my APID to respond, even without the GCM account being correct. But I cannot receive any push notifications. More specifically, there are certain parts of the androidManifest.xml that need to be kept the same. This is my androidManifest.xml configuration:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myCompany.myGame" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

   <!-- The com.prime31.EtceteraApplication should be there -->
   <application android:name="com.prime31.EtceteraApplication"
                android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:debuggable="true">

    <!-- These activities should be in there -->
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="behind"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>

    <!-- ACTIVITIES -->
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.EtceteraProxyActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.WebViewActivity" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.P31VideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.c2dm.C2DMPushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.myCompany.myGame" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.myCompany.myGame" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:process=":com.urbanairship.push.process" />
    <receiver android:name="com.prime31.P31UAIntentReceiver" />
</application>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>

<permission android:name="com.myCompany.myGame.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.myCompany.myGame.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

If you manage to get push notifications to work, please let me know since I can't get that part to work! Cheers!